# Clustered white spots on strawberry mint leaves

Tags: diseases, mint, discoloration

I woke up this morning to find a node of leaves on my strawberry mint plant covered in white spots.
[image: strawberry mint leaves with white spots]

I've noticed a few other leaves nearby having the same issue, though not as prominent.

Does anyone know what this is? Should I be concerned?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [Powdery Mildew](https://www.almanac.com/pest/powdery-mildew), it's a very common fungal disease.

Try pruning the affected plant parts. Additionally, try to increase air circulation around your plants and avoid watering the plants from overhead - fungal diseases thrive in humid conditions, and decreasing dampness around your plants should help.

Naturally, applying fungicidal treatments is recommended, preferably one that is specific for treating Powdery Mildew, but a baking soda solution or neem oil should help too. [Source](https://www.gardendesign.com/how-to/powdery-mildew.html)

Comment: Ah, I think the conditions were perfect for it. It has been raining everyday for the past week. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome! Please upvote and accept my answer if it has been helpful to you :)